# Powershell: How to deal with values of grouped objects?

Tags: powershell, email, foreach

I have an excel list with two columns as following:

## Excelfile

```
+--------+------------+
| File   | Email      |
+--------+------------+
| 0001   | A@mail.com |
| 0004   | B@mail.com |
| 0005   | C@mail.com |
| 0008   | B@mail.com |
+--------+------------+
```

I want to use a PowerShell script to send an email to each user and attach all the files that are related to the specific user. For example the userA will only get one file (c:\temp\0001.pdf) and userB will get two files attached to his email (c:\temp\0004.pdf and c:\temp\0008.pdf) and so on.

I can read my excel file using the powershell module ImportExcel and group the content by the email address. And I also can send a single email in a different powershell script. But I don't know how to link those two code snippets since I'm a powershell beginner. Any help would be very much appreciated.

## Code part 1

```
$exceldata = (Import-Excel -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\testdata.xlsx")
$groupeddata = ($exceldata | Group-Object -Property Email)
```

## The result set I get is the following

```
+-------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Count | Name       | Group                                                            |
+-------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1     | A@mail.com | {@{File=0001; Email=A@mail.com}}                                 |
| 2     | B@mail.com | {@{File=0004; Email=B@mail.com}, @{File=0008; Email=B@mail.com}} |
| 1     | C@mail.com | {@{File=0005; Email=C@mail.com}}                                 |
+-------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

## Code part 2

```
Send-MailMessage -To "B@mail.com" -From "DB Admin <dbadmin@xyx.com>" -SMTPServer smtp1.xyz.com -Subject "Monthly report" -Body "Please check attached files" -Attachments "c:\temp\0004.pdf", "c:\temp\0008.pdf"
```

works as well.

But how can I link those two code snippets? Any help would be very much appreciated since I'm a Powershell script beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using something like this to get your code working.  I mocked some of your data, but you can see that the `$group` is like your `$groupeddata`.

The key is looking at the data structures in the debugger, and figuring out how to access the members you want.  Using `foreach` over each one let's you operate on each entry in the group.

```
$data = @'
File, Email
0001, A@email.com,
0004, B@email.com,
0005, C@email.com,
0008, B@email.com,
'@

$xls = $data | ConvertFrom-Csv

$group = $xls | Group -Property Email

foreach ($entry in $group)
{
    $email = $entry.Name
    $files = ($entry.Group.File | % {'c:\temp\'+$_+'.pdf'}) -join ', '

    # debugging...look at this in debugger ISE or VSCode
    "$email and $files"

    # uncomment to actually run the command...
    #Send-MailMessage -To $email -From "DB Admin <dbadmin@xyx.com>" -SMTPServer smtp1.xyz.com -Subject "Monthly report" -Body "Please check attached files" -Attachments $files
}
```